# What actually happens when light meets a surface(QED or QM or Condensed matter physics)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, quantum-electrodynamics

I want to know what actually happens when light meets a surface like water or wood.

Quantum mechanics says that objects are neither "transparent" nor "opaque". Rather a system as a whole can accept "energy packets" in certain ranges of energy and has no states available to accept other ranges of energy. If something is "transparent" it means its energy level structure (for crystal systems this is called the "band structure") is such that it can't accept energy packets between ~1.7eV to 3.0eV which corresponds to light in the visible spectrum with wavelengths of 700nm (red) to 400nm (violet). There is of course nothing special about that particular energy range except that it happens to be the range that our human eyes have evolved to see. If I instead, for example, looked in the infrared range, like in this image:

[image]

<sup>[Image source](http://www.jwst.nasa.gov/exhibit/infrared.html)</sup>

I'd see that the man's eyeglasses are in fact opaque in that range (meaning that the glass does accept energy packets corresponding to the infrared range, even if it didn't in the visual range) and what he's holding there is a "black" garbage bag, which is in fact transparent to that range of light.
Here's the same picture in the visual range:

[image]

<sup>[Image source](http://www.jwst.nasa.gov/exhibit/infrared.html)</sup>

While quantum electrodynamics says it works on by adding (magnitude only not direction) vectors (from the strange theory of light and matter) you start the stopwatch when photon leaves the light source and you stop the watch when the photon reaches the photo-detector, and then add the two vectors or more to get the resultant vector, which tells whether reflection or refraction will take place.

What actually happens when light meets surface like water, glass or wood? Which is right: QM or QED? Am I missing something in QED that I don't know (because it's called most complete theory of light) or it is best explained by condensed matter physics?

Comment: "has no states available to accept other ranges of energy" $-$ probably you forgot that there are in-band transitions. E.g. in the valence band some positions are occupied, so these electrons (+ photons + phonons) may leap to a free state. And there are some surface states due to charges collected there, effectively creating new energy levels located near the surface.

Answer (score 3):

Quantum electrodynamics is part of quantum mechanics and is the mathematical method used to calculate quantities rather than hand wave explanations.

What you call "quantum mechanics " is a hand waved explanation, not wrong, but no numbers can come out of it because light is composed of zillions of photons impinging on other zillions of electrons making up the fields of the solids. It thus is a many body problem, and the appropriate tool for numerical results is classical electrodynamics, with its index of refraction etc. The classical emerges from the QED mathematical form in a [rather convoluted way, but smoothly.](http://motls.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.html). If you read the link you will understand the complications of using the QED tool for a set up where classical electrodynamics excels in describing and predicting.

A single photon impinging on a lattice of atoms defines a quantum mechanical problem with its boundary conditions and the solution gives the probability of scatter and the probability of transparency, i.e exiting the material in a coherent way without loosing energy  .  But a single photon is not light.

Edit to expand on comments:

There are many "theories"  which in reality are models trying to reduce a many body problem( light with zillions of photons impinging on zillions of atoms) to a simpler picture. The model of photons absorbed and re-emitted like passing a ball from one atom to another cannot be the case because at the quantum mechanical level energy levels are discrete and in addition the angular distribution would change for each absorption. There may exist models with phonons  but they   also are  a collective approximation within solids.

My view is that the velocity of a single photon cannot be measured, because every measurement is an interaction and  interactions change the quantum mechanical boundary condition problem. In addition the velocity of light is enormous and the delta(time) of "stopwatches" in any experimental setup is limited,

In contrast to individual photons the velocity  of the classical em wave can be measured in vacuum over large distances, and by the index of refraction within materials. As with a wave in water, where the velocity of the wave is a coherent collective result of the transport of energy by waves in water but the individual molecules have their own motions, the electromagnetic  wave in the quantum detail of the photons is built up by photons that move with velocity c , but the phase angles in the build up of photons to classical wave allow for a collective change in the wave velocity when in a medium,  i.e. the velocity of the transport of energy of the electromagnetic wave can be different than for the vacuum.

That the velocity of a photon is c is a consequence of the Lorentz invariance which holds at the elementary particle level. This invariance has been tested with a large number of measurements and is continually validated.

Comment: This is an interesting and useful answer but I'm not sure it addresses the question. OP is thinking of adding vectors together, with their phases determined by a stopwatch, as a means to calculate whether or not a material is transparent. The vector adding procedure he mentions is for computing (free space) diffraction patterns, which has nothing directly to do with transparency of a material. In principle one can use the same *principles* of adding phases to compute properties of the solid (i.e. use QFT), but OP didn't mention that at all.

Comment: @DanielSank well he is asking in the last paragraph about who is right, QM or QED. Except if QED means something different than Quantum ElectroDynamics  in this context.

Comment: Right but the problem is that OP has a misguided notion of what it means to apply QED to the two slit problem. Therefore, I'm not sure that explaining that QED underlies classical E&M really has anything to do with the question.

Comment: @DanielSank Hmm. You are talking about the paragraph before last which refers to an unknown to me link and the content is unfamilier. The title and the end question say something else and that is what I am addressing.

Comment: If you read what OP think's QED means you'll see that OP's understanding is misguided. Read the whole post carefully. You can and did answer the literal question in the last paragraph, but I don't think that really addresses why OP is confused.

Comment: I am talking about what Feynman discusses about, in the book The strange theory light and matter,when he says that out of 100 photons 4 are partially reflected and 96 are transmitted,and how many photons are refracted or transmitted depends on the thickness of the glass, which he then demonstrates by using stopwatch,he places two photodetectors one above the glass and one below the glass, and starts the stopwatch when the photon moves from the light source and stops it when it has reached either of the photodetectors. My question is which one is right QM(energy band) or QED(using stopwatch) ?

Comment: One cannot use stop watches on photons, they are too fast. It must be a thought experiment exaggerating the situation. Both ways of looking at it are correct quantum mechanically one photon at a time. The percentages build up the probability function , the function is predicted by the qm solution and, if one went to the trouble, the QED solution (using creation and annihilation operators). Still light is better studied in the classical framework.

Comment: Here's another theory - https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/do-photons-move-slower-in-a-solid-medium.511177/

Comment: All these "theories" are models trying to reduce a many body problem( light with zillions of photons impinging on zillions of atoms) to a simpler picture. I agree that the model of  photons  absorbed and re-emitted like passing a ball from one atom to another cannot be the case because at the quantum mechanical level energy levels are discrete and in addition the angular distribution would change for each absorption. Phonons are also a collective approximation within solids. My view is that the velocity of a single photon cannot be measured, because every measurement is an interaction

Comment: and interactions change the quantum mechanical boundary condition problem. The  v of the classical em wave can be measured in vacuum over large distances, and by the index of refraction within materials.As with a wave in water, where the velocity of the wave is a coherent collective result of the transport of energy but the individual molecules have their own motions, the em wave in the quantum detail of the photons is built up by photons that move with velocity c , but the phase angles in the build up of photons to classical wave allow for a collective change in the wave velocity.

Comment: If/when you understand the content of the link to Motl's article of how classical emerges from quantum you will understand what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

You've confused two things.
The business with adding vectors whose direction is determined by the stopwatch tells you what kind of interference pattern you'd see on a screen after the light [diffracts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction) through an aperture.
In this case you're assuming you have an opaque screen with which to view the diffraction pattern.
This is entirely independent of the question of a material's internal energy level structure which, as you say, determines whether that material is opaque or transparent to a particular wavelength of light.